# Want to perform left join in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-filter, django-3.2

Say I've 2 models

```
Model Users:
       Name:
       Id:
```

And attendance

```
Model Attendance:
   user: foreign_key(User)
   present: [present if login else nothing recorded]
   Date:


users = User.objects.all()
todays_present = Attendance.objects.filter(date=today)
```

Now for instance
Users = 10
todays_present = 7

I want to find which three users are not in todays_present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with [**`.exclude(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) with:

```
User.objects.exclude(attendance__date=today)
```

This will retrieve all users for which no `Attendance` can be found where the `date` field is equal to `today`.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you the actual user objects not attendant for `today` (though Willem Van Onsem's solution is simpler).

You may need to adjust `'attendance_set'` depending on your actual model related name.

```
users_not_present_today = User.objects.annotate(
  today_attendance_count=Count('attendance_set', filter=Q(present=True, date=today)
).filter(today_attendance_count=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of thanks to these two guys @willem and @AKX, who made me think in correct direction.

What I did is, first get all present employees with

```
presents = Attendance.objects.filter(date=today)
```

then exclude them from all users like:

```
absent = User.objects.exclude(attendance_set__in=presents)
```

This worded How I wanted it be...